# video js giving error CODE:150 undefined

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, server, video.js

I am using video js plugin to play youtube videos. It is giving me following error

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:150 undefined)
```

I am using following code

```
<script src="resources/js/video.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/youtube.js"></script>


 <video id="vid2" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="360" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ED0EBHn8_uw" }'>
  </video>
```

Currently I am running this video on new purchased hosting account of reck space Whereas the same code is working on my previous server of godaddy.

One more thing if I change youtube video url to

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjS6SftYQaQ
```

then it is working on current server as well while any other video is not working. :(

I have tried https and http both.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: What version of video JS are you using? Can you provide a sample setup that replicates this error? It might be as simple as not having updated the paths on the new webserver.

Comment: using videojs version (v4.12.6 )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found a solution for this issue but I solved it by setting the "Allow embedding" as checked in the advanced video settings on youtube.